# How to build a w3c document in groovy?

Tags: groovy, w3c

I'm want to build a w3c xml node in groovy :

```
def CAR_RECORDS = '''<records>
             <car name='HSV Maloo' make='Holden' year='2006'/>
             <car name='P50' make='Peel' year='1962'/>
             <car name='Royale' make='Bugatti' year='1931'/>
           </records>
         '''

        def carRecords = new XmlParser().parseText(CAR_RECORDS)
```

but all I get using the MarkupBuilder is a groovy.util.Node ( carRecords is a groovy.util.Node ). 
Is there an elegant way (that doesn't require standard java xml coding) to do this?

What I'm looking for is something that will look like this:

```
def carRecords = new W3CXmlParser().parseText(CAR_RECORDS)
```

or anything of the kind...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple way (pseudo code):

- Create a tree structure with `MarkupBuilder`
- Convert that into an string with XML markup
- Parse that String to get W3C DOM nodes

Background: The W3C DOM API is very unfriendly from a Groovy point of view which is why the `MarkupBuilder` uses its own type.

Which is why Groovy supports the inverse operation: Convert W3C DOM nodes to `groovy.util.Node`s using `DomToGroovy`

See also: [Creating XML using Groovy's MarkupBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Creating+XML+using+Groovy%27s+MarkupBuilder)

Answer (score 1):

I might have the wrong end of the stick, but is this what you wanted to do?:

```
import org.xml.sax.InputSource
import org.w3c.dom.Node
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory

def CAR_RECORDS = '''<records>
  <car name='HSV Maloo' make='Holden' year='2006'/>
  <car name='P50' make='Peel' year='1962'/>
  <car name='Royale' make='Bugatti' year='1931'/>
</records>'''

Node carRecords = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                                        .newDocumentBuilder()
                                        .parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( CAR_RECORDS ) ) )
```